# Create a scatterplot in ggplot2 (R) using two different dataframes with similar x axes and different y axes scales

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to create a scatterplot with that visualises two different dataframes on the same plot. Df1 is acoustic backscatter over time whereas df2 is total catch over time. Both df's have similar x-axes of dates but have totally different y axes scales. Df1 is in decibels so the values are negative, df2 has a scale in kg's. I am able to make a rudimentary version of the desired graph using the following code:

```
ggplot(aes(x=date_column, y=Sv_log), data=daily_avg_stn1) + geom_point() + 
  geom_point(aes(x=date_column, y=total_catch), data=Dai15E) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name="Sv", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 1*., name="kg"))
```

Which produces this graph:
[image]

As you can see, both axes follow the scaling for df2, leaving the points for df1 unable to be really seen.

Is there a way to plot the data on the same graph using different scales on the y-axes that will actually visualise them properly?

I do want to add that I understand that this visualisation method is often considered 'flawed' and I agree with this sentiment in the vast majority of cases. In this instance, the y axes data from both datasets are reflective of one another, so I believe it would be useful here. Df1 is how much 'stuff' was detected in the water whereas df2 is how much fish was physically pulled from the water in the same location.

Here is reprex data if it is needed: df1 relevant cols are 'Sv_log' and 'date_column')

```
structure(list(Date_time = structure(c(1607857200, 1607943600, 
1608030000, 1608116400, 1608202800, 1608289200, 1608375600, 1608462000, 
1608548400, 1608634800, 1608721200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "Asia/Bangkok"), DayNight = c("Day", "Day", "Day", 
"Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day"), Sv_Ln = c(1.74677825962786e-07, 
1.22055385703042e-07, 2.19152503837621e-07, 3.11979082335984e-07, 
4.84130876637067e-07, 3.1165372476377e-07, 3.54254648288666e-07, 
5.71260068783433e-07, 9.48339907695522e-07, 1.38434839536466e-06, 
1.25563385475358e-06), Sv_log = c(-67.577622219387, -69.1344305254743, 
-66.5925356312706, -65.0587452370783, -63.1503721827736, -65.063276782227, 
-64.5068444252616, -62.4316613216752, -60.2303597323357, -58.5875459835948, 
-59.0113698324402), date_column = structure(c(18609, 18610, 18611, 
18612, 18613, 18614, 18615, 18616, 18617, 18618, 18619), class = "Date"), 
    peak_status = c("Off-Peak", "Off-Peak", "Off-Peak", "Off-Peak", 
    "Off-Peak", "Off-Peak", "Off-Peak", "Off-Peak", "Off-Peak", 
    "Off-Peak", "Off-Peak"), Days = c(13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
    19, 20, 21, 22, 23)), row.names = 13:23, class = "data.frame")
```

df2 relevant cols are 'total_catch' and 'date_column')

```
structure(list(Trip = c("T7", "T7", "T7", "T7", "T7", "T7", "T7", 
"T7", "T7", "T7", "T7"), Dai = c("Dai15E", "Dai15E", "Dai15E", 
"Dai15E", "Dai15E", "Dai15E", "Dai15E", "Dai15E", "Dai15E", "Dai15E", 
"Dai15E"), sampleID = c("S03", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S03", 
"S03", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S04"), Date_S = structure(c(18663, 
18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 
18663), class = "Date"), Time_S = structure(c(39000, 39000, 39000, 
39000, 39000, 39000, 39000, 39000, 39000, 39000, 47400), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), Date_E = structure(c(18663, 18663, 
18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663
), class = "Date"), Time_E = structure(c(47400, 47400, 47400, 
47400, 47400, 47400, 47400, 47400, 47400, 47400, 56400), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), total_catch = c(120, 120, 120, 
120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 50), Subsample.kg. = c(5.1, 
5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 4.5), Scientific_Name = c("Pangasius.elongatus", 
"Rasbora.aurotaenia", "Amblyrhynchichthys.micracanthus", "Osteochilus.schlegelii", 
"Gymnostomus.lobatus", "Phalacronotus.sp1", "Polynemus.melanochir", 
"Labeo.chrysophekadion", "Acantopsis.ioa", "Kryptopterus.geminus", 
"Labiobarbus.leptocheilus"), Abundance = c(1L, 8L, 13L, 1L, 31L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 213L), weight = c(13.8, 47.9, 72.7, 6.4, 
145.9, 4.7, 88.5, 3.8, 3.9, 23.5, 1324.4), note = c("Sampling", 
"Sampling", "Sampling", "Sampling", "Sampling", "Sampling", "Sampling", 
"Sampling", "Sampling", "Sampling", "Sampling"), Date_time_S = structure(c(1612497000, 
1612497000, 1612497000, 1612497000, 1612497000, 1612497000, 1612497000, 
1612497000, 1612497000, 1612497000, 1612505400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Bangkok"), Date_time_E = structure(c(1612505400, 
1612505400, 1612505400, 1612505400, 1612505400, 1612505400, 1612505400, 
1612505400, 1612505400, 1612505400, 1612514400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Bangkok"), Duration = c(2.33333333333333, 
2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 
2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 
2.33333333333333, 2.5), Time_M = structure(c(43200, 43200, 43200, 
43200, 43200, 43200, 43200, 43200, 43200, 43200, 51900), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), unique_id = c("T7 S03", "T7 S03", 
"T7 S03", "T7 S03", "T7 S03", "T7 S03", "T7 S03", "T7 S03", "T7 S03", 
"T7 S03", "T7 S04"), DayNight = c("Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", 
"Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day"), date_column = structure(c(18663, 
18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 
18663), class = "Date"), peak_status = c("Off-Peak", "Off-Peak", 
"Off-Peak", "Off-Peak", "Off-Peak", "Off-Peak", "Off-Peak", "Off-Peak", 
"Off-Peak", "Off-Peak", "Off-Peak"), peak = c("Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", 
"Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", 
"Non-Peak", "Non-Peak", "Non-Peak"), log_catch = c(20.7918124604762, 
20.7918124604762, 20.7918124604762, 20.7918124604762, 20.7918124604762, 
20.7918124604762, 20.7918124604762, 20.7918124604762, 20.7918124604762, 
20.7918124604762, 16.9897000433602), Family = c("Pangasiidae", 
"Danionidae", "Cyprinidae", "Cyprinidae", "Cyprinidae", "Siluridae", 
"Polynemidae", "Cyprinidae", "Cobitidae", "Siluridae", "Cyprinidae"
)), row.names = 1889:1899, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Reproducible data is always required so thanks for that. Unfortunately none of the dates in your example `df2` match with `df1`: there is only one day, and one `total_catch` value. Could you provide example data with matching dates and more varied values?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, let me fix that.

Comment: I changed the reprex data, df2 only has one day in it but that day is in df1. That should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most of the questions posted here about a secondary axis in ggplot, the answer is that adding a secondary axis *doesn't change the geoms plotted in the panel*. It is just an annotation. You need to transform the *data* you are plotting. The secondary axis is just a yardstick for the transformed data.

Start by applying some transformation to the `total_catch` values that makes them approximately level with the `Sv_log` data. For example, dividing by ten and subtracting 70 works quite well. Then draw on a secondary axis that reverses this transformation (adding 70 then multiplying by 10):

```r
ggplot(aes(x=date_column, y=Sv_log), data=df1) + geom_point() + 
  geom_point(aes(x=date_column, y=total_catch/10 - 70), data=df2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name="Sv", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. + 70)*10, name="kg"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is essentially what im looking for (was playing with the scaling), but for some reason when I run this my 'Sv' axis doesnt show negatives and just listed 0 to 100.  Very close, I guess I just need to keep experimenting with scaling until I reach the desired result?

Comment: I worked it out. This solved my issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to a base R solution (I am partial to base R plotting), you could create it with something like below, where `par(new = TRUE)` will overlay the `df2` plot. Here I plotted the `df2` values in `darkred` and the `df1` values in `darkgrey`. Your sample data were great (thank you!) but they only had one functional value in `df2` (`date_column` dates were all 2020-11-25 and `total_catch` value all = 20) but I tried to code it assuming these would be different (see commented out `axis`. Good luck!

```
xx <- range(range(df1$date_column), range(df2$date_column))
par(mar = c(5,5,5,5))

plot(df1$date_column, y = df1$Sv_log, xlim = xx, ylim = range(df1$Sv_log), 
     frame = FALSE, axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "",
     pch = 21, bg = "darkgrey")
axis(2, at = seq(min(df1$Sv_log), max(df1$Sv_log), length.out = 5), 
     label = round(seq(min(df1$Sv_log), max(df1$Sv_log), length.out = 5), 2))

par(new = TRUE)

plot(x = df2$date_column, y = df2$total_catch, xlim = xx, 
     frame = FALSE, pch = 21, bg = "darkred", axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
# add in axes
axis(1, at = seq.Date(min(xx), max(xx), by = "week"), label = seq.Date(min(xx), max(xx), by = "week"))
axis(4, at = seq(15, 25, by = 5)) # sample data were limited, so this was just manual, see below for how I would do it in full dataset
  # axis(4, at = seq(min(df2$total_catch), max(df2$total_catch), length.out = 5))
mtext("Date", 1, padj = 5)
mtext("Sv", 2, padj = -5)
mtext("kg", 4, padj = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: This did work wonderfully, however, I will have to try to convert it to ggplot2. This will be going into a publication and the graphs need to have the same design theme. Is it possible to save all this to the environment and then add it to a ggplot string?

Comment: @JacksonASwan I’m very glad you found a `ggplot2` solution! Im not sure if a ggplot/base hybrid would have worked for you. Keeping this here in case it helps others

Comment: It's a very good solution and worked great. Really makes me rethink using ggplot2 as my standard figure-making package.